# Can't install vim-gnome

Tags: gnome, vim

On the last Ubunt 14.04 upgrade I'm not able to install `vim-gnome` anymore due the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  vim-gnome : Depends:
vim-gui-common (= 2:7.4.640-1~ppa1~t) but it is not going to be
installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.
```

Tried to remove absolutely everything related to vim and reinstall, but no success.

Comment: I'd bet you're using pi-rho's PPA (https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev). Remove the PPA and try again.

Comment: Sweeet! It worked! I removed the ppa, removed vim and installed again and it works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [pi-rho's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) has a broken build of Vim. Until this is fixed, it might be best to use another PPA, or no PPA at all. As an alternative, try the [Vim Daily builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pkg-vim/+archive/ubuntu/vim-daily), which apparently hasn't been updated in the last couple of weeks, but is still pretty current.